# CL+SSL SSL Error: Unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled. How to bypass or resolve?

Tags: ssl, openssl, common-lisp, sbcl, drakma

I'm trying to hit an https endpoint to pull back some data using common-lisp(sbcl). For a while this worked without issue. Then one day I started receiving the following error

```
SSL error queue:
error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
   [Condition of type CL+SSL::SSL-ERROR-SSL]
```

I've tried using both drakma and dexador, but see the same error from both. I've confirmed through openssl that the server I'm trying to connect to does not support renegotiation.

From `openssl s_client -connect`

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
```

I'm on OSX and my open ssl version is LibreSSL 2.8.3.

So to my understanding my client is trying to initiate renegotiation, but the server is rejecting it. I don't really know where to go from here and at this point I'm not even sure what level the problem is truly at, openSSL, CL+SSL, or the http client libraries built on top of CL+SSL. Is there some way to disable renegotiation, or force a new connection? Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Is there any luck in resolving this issue ... ?

Comment: Unsafe renegotiation can be enabled again using the "-legacy_renegotiation" parameter. e.g. `openssl s_client -connect www.google.de:443 -legacy_renegotiation`

Answer (score 2):

In Openssl 1.1.1, the SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT flag was turned on by default, but
It is turned off by default as of Openssl 3.0.0.

check the article below

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT);
```

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_clear_options.html

Comment: Hi!  I got an openssl version 3 from creating a new conda environment then running "conda install -c conda-forge gdal"  .  I don't understand from your comment how I can enable SSL_OP_LEVACY_SERVER_CONNECT.  is this a flag you modify when you "make" the openssl, or something you change in a config file?

Comment: A manual for SSL_CONF_cmd shows the corresponding command-line option `-legacy_server_connect`.